# how to open a link in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

With the help of this code i can open url in new tab instead of that how to open this url as a popup in the same window

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(shiny::fluidRow(shiny::actionButton(inputId='ab1', 
label="click here", value = "Open popup",onclick ="window.open('http://google.com','_blank')")))

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just wanted a resizable browser tab popup, for this you edit the `JS` and add `resizable` argument:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(shiny::fluidRow(shiny::actionButton(inputId='ab1', 
                                                    label="click here", value = "Open popup",onclick ="window.open('http://google.com','_blank','resizable,height=260,width=370')")))

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: i want to show the url as a pop not a msg sir or else can you tell me how to open the url in new window which can alter by size @Pork CHop

Comment: this is ok but is this possible to open this url as a pop in the same window

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
onclick = 'window.open("http://google.com", "Google", "width=480,height=360,resizable=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,status=no")'
```

Comment: where to check about resizeble toolbar menubar location stats and all @Stephane Laurent